# How to move all non-null values to the top of my column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in my table:

```
   | Id  |  lIST_1      |
   ----------------------
   | 1   |  NULL        |
   | 2   |  JASON       |
   | 3   |  NULL        |    
   | 4   |  BANDORAN    |
   | 5   |  NULL        |
   | 6   |  NULL        | 
   | 7   |  SMITH       | 
   | 8   |  NULL        |
```

How can I write a query to get the output below?

```
   | Id  |  lIST_1      
   -----------------------
   | 1   |  JASON        |
   | 2   |  BANDORAN     |
   | 3   |  SMITH        |  
   | 4   |  NULL         |
   | 5   |  NULL         |
   | 6   |  NULL         |
   | 7   |  NULL         |
   | 8   |  NULL         |
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by`:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id, t.list_1
from t
order by (case when list_1 is not null then 1 else 2 end)
```

It is unclear why you would want `id` to change values, but you can use `row_number()` for that.

EDIT:

If you want to change the `id`, then you can do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select row_number() over (order by (case when list_id is not null then 1 else 2 end), id
                               ) as new_id,
             t.*
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set id = new_id
    where id <> new_id;  -- no need to update if the value remains the same
```

Comment: tanx Gordon Because I want to send them for an object, if they are null values ​​between them will be sent. now how i can update my column , this query just select my table